# debugging Intel's TBB containers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multithreading, tbb

Recently we have started working with Intel's TBB and found that when debugging containers we cannot really watch the elements and their data.

Is there a flag setting, a plugin or a tricky way to enable this?  (maybe a script snipit for Visual to work with)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [expression evaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fwk67y3%28VS.80%29.aspx). You can't do this with a simple flag, as there are an infinite number of data structures. But an expression evaluator is indeed a kind of plugin, it's definitely code.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed something like that - but, is there any place something like that already exists for the TBB?    that would save so much time :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not answering your question "is there one" since I don't know, but instead of using an expression evaluator I'd use a custom visualizer. They're a pain to write but work relatively well afterwards.

The best resource is:
http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=120

Answer (score 1):

TBB is a relatively new (but exciting) library, and I won't expect extensive tools for debugging right now. You might try to implement a simple ring buffer (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-buffer/index.html) for logging and debugging.